# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '95600000_1410688544-0-2' for key 3

Tags: magento-1.7, reindex

I have following error message after reindex rewrites:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '95600000_1410688544-0-2' for key 3

How can I find this product?
What is: 95600000_1410688544-0-2? 
And what is: for key 3?

Comment: can you tell me ? latest product id?

Comment: it can report index issue.some duplicated entry  in report_event table

Comment: After all I've read, the report_event table can be safely truncated (after a backup, of course); maybe truncating solves the issue, of if u reset the auto_increment value

Comment: is it resolved or not?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer :  if it resolved your issue. Feel free to put an answer and accept it.